# Target GIFs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, gif

Is there a way to target all the GIFs src? I want to apply a JS code to just GIFs.

This is the code I have at the moment, but it's targeting the img:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner img').each(function () {
      var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', curSrc.split('?')[0]);
    });
});
```

EDITED: The GIFs have params (that's why I am using the code above, to remove those params), so I can't target the final string as it's is not .gif

This is how the HTML looks: `<img src="/asset/News/6001/gif-anim.gif?thumbnail_width=2000&amp;thumbnail_height=500&amp;resize_type=CropToFit" height="500" width="2000" alt="">`

Comment: can you share some relevant html codes?

Comment: the fact it's a gif is probably only revealed by the file extension. So you'd have to parse the file extension (e.g. look at the last 3 characters, or use a regular expression). I think you're nearly there right now - you've already got the URL minus any querystring, so you just want to get the last 3 characters of that string and see if they equal "gif" or not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods#Methods_2

Comment: Assuming your file formats are consistent, use the [Attribute Ends With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector on those images, looking for `.gif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the file extension with `indexOf` and find which img is GIF and which not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner img').each(function () {
      var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');
      if(curSrc.indexOf('.gif')!=-1 || curSrc.indexOf('.GIF')!=-1) {
             $(this).attr('src', curSrc.split('?')[0]);
             console.log("It is GIF");
       } else {
               console.log("It is not GIF");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: This code `$(this).attr('src', curSrc.split('?')[0]);` is already changing the `src` and I'd like to change it just if it's a GIF, but I can't find the way to do it

Comment: you can put src change code inside if condition. see updated post